# Call an Android service from mobile browser

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-service, mobile-browser

I have to start a service when user click on a button from a web page.
I know it is possible to do that with an Activity by adding this in the manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name="MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" /> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

my idea was to do the same for a service :

```
<service
        android:name="MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter >
            <data android:scheme="myscheme"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

but it doesn't work.

So is it possible to call the service from the browser and how to do?
If not, what can I do (I don't want an application view appear when the user click on the web page button)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it possible to call the service

No, except by perhaps launching an activity and having that activity do something with your service.

> (I don't want an application view appear when the user click on the web page button)?

You are welcome to create a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity, which calls `startService()` from its `onCreate()`, then immediately calls `finish()`.